# Angularjs ui-router add parent url parameter to current state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-parameters

This is my app state

```
  .state('app', {
      url: "/?:site_id",
      templateUrl: "/controls/angular/templates/partial/app.html",
      abstract: true
  })
  .state('app.popup', {
    url: "popup",
    templateUrl: "/controls/angular/templates/popup.html",
    controller: 'PopupController'
  })
```

The app root (that config as abstract) has parameter (site_id) that I can use in all other pages in the application.

I have drop-down list that can change the site.
How can I add the site url parameter to current page with all other parameters that exist

Just change the root site_id parameter.

```
     var oSelect =  $('#site_select_tag').select2();
        oSelect.on("change", function (e) {
       var curr_site_id = e.val;                                
       $state.go to => ?????????                               
       //scope.site_id = e.val;
       scope.onChange()(e.val);
});
```

Comment: Are you looking to pass the parameters in ``$state.go`` ??

Comment: I don't know what the options to add single parameter to current state (with parameters), I add the "state go" just for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks

The solution is simple

```
$state.go('.', {site_id: e.val})
```

Keep all other parameters and set the new parameter

Comment: quick and easy way. It should be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass options to the `go` method of `$state`:

> $state.go(to [, toParams] [, options])

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options

```
$state.go('myState', {'myParam': myValue});
```

And you can set parameters on `ui-sref`:

> ui-sref='stateName({param: value, param: value})'

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref

```
<a ui-sref="myState({'myParam': myValue})">myLink</a>
```

You can access the current state as `$state.current.name` and the current parameters as `$state.params` so what you can do is this:

```
var params = $state.params;
params.id = 123; // Set new ID
$state.go($state.current.name, params);
```

Comment: But like I said I don't know what the state is and what the other parameters are.

Comment: Ok, edited my answer. Hope i understood you correctly this time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly your trying to manipulate the state data after it is set up in the $stateProvider. If so you should set up your own state provider like [Mean.io](https://github.com/linnovate/mean/blob/master/packages/core/system/public/routes/system.js) do

```
// $meanStateProvider, provider to wire up $viewPathProvider to $stateProvider
angular.module('mean.system').provider('$meanState', ['$stateProvider', '$viewPathProvider', function($stateProvider,viewPathProvider){
    function MeanStateProvider() {
        this.state = function(stateName, data) {
          if (data.templateUrl) {
            data.templateUrl = $viewPathProvider.path(data.templateUrl);
          }        
          $stateProvider.state(stateName, data);        
          return this;
        };    

        this.$get = function() {
          return this;
        };
    }
    return new MeanStateProvider();
    }]);
```